# google.com gets redirected to google.co.il

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

A similar question was asked before but I believe my situation is different.
Out of nowhere, when I type in `google.com`, the google page gets redirected to `google.co.il`
When I followed google's instruction and did a simple search, at the end of the search result page, it clearly states my correct geo location - `New York, NY - from your internet address`.
Without using `google.com/ncr` to get to `google.com`, if I type `google.com`, it gets redirected to `google.co.il`. 
Whether I use firefox or chrome it's all the same. What's going on here? Firefox says it's a problem from google. Any idea? Great many thanks

Comment: This isn't on topic here. Isn't there a "use google.com" link to the bottom right though?

Comment: can remove this thread, but would like to confirm two things - (a) is stackoverflow NOT the place to post such a question (a similar question was posted here in the past though); (b) yes, there is a "use google.com" link, and when i click on it, the page does get redirected to google.com. but now the "use google.com" link changes to "use google.co.il" and I wonder how google.co.il gets there in the first place. Any idea ? (or what forum should I post my inquiry)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask questions about web browsers unless they are *programming* questions about web browsers. Superuser.com *might* work. (Re the google.co.il, I have no idea what could cause this - weird. You don't have a VPN to Israel somewhere in your connection?)

Comment: Will just keep the post up until it gets closed. Regarding VPN, my internet connection is through an internet service provider in USA (or even locally New York) so I am not sure how my VPN all of a sudden has Israel somewhere in the connection. Thanks for your time providing some answers though.